# On Android app how to display only part of a webpage

Tags: android, android-webview

I have no idea if this is possible but..

I want to try and show on my app a small part of this webpage 
http://magicseaweed.com/Praia-da-Rocha-Surf-Report/127/

namely this

[img1 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2253656/Screenshot%20at%202012-05-16%2022%3A38%3A07.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2253656/Screenshot%20at%202012-05-16%2022%3A38%3A07.png)

or another example from http://www.infopraias.com/reportpraia.asp?ID=3

[img2 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2253656/teste2.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2253656/teste2.jpg)

what I needed is to get some info to show on my app, and it's usually on a portion of a webpage, just a .

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

First, you should know that the android market terms of service prohibit unauthorized use of web services (which includes a 'web page').

Now that you know that, you can scrape web pages for data using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Drop the JAR into your project, make a folder called 'libs'. Right click it and add to build path.

Then try this, the example from their main page:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

(Note: Don't scrape wikipedia...  They ban fast)

You just need to inspect the DOM of the page you want to grab data from and decide what a good selector is. That there, is a CSS selector. Another way to do this is with xpath: https://norrisshelton.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/jsoup-java-html-parser/

Comment: Hi! I wasn't aware of this "First, you should know that the android market terms of service prohibit unauthorized use of web services (which includes a 'web page')." .. For example, I have a weather app and it gets info from the web about the weather.. wouldn't this be kind of the same thing?

Comment: It means that I should provide the info I want somewhere online? I noticed also some websites have embed code of windguru ( http://www.windguru.cz/int/help_index.php?sec=distr ) couldn't I do something like this with embed iframe?

Answer (score -1):

I agree, don't go scrapping where you don't belong.

Another option is use Javascript to get the data off of the page through the DOM Tree ([tutorial on  that here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics)).

In order to that you will need to enable javascript and add a Javascript WebChromeClient:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
// register class containing methods to be exposed to JavaScript
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

/**
 * Provides a hook for calling "alert" from javascript. Useful for
 * debugging your javascript.
 */
final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result)     {
        Log.d("DEBUG", message);
    }
}
```

Then you can alert out values that you have scrape off the page by alerting them by something like:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(document.getElementsByClassName('mainbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('b')[1].innerText);");
```

Comment: hi @Spencer .. "don't go scrapping where you don't belong.", you mean getting info from the web if it's not my website?
Thanks for the help

Comment: yes @cornelyus, if someone else is funding and hosting a website, and you go in a just pull their data without asking first, that's bad.